# MySQL join, most recent, group by, limit to 1 result per id

Tags: mysql, join, syntax

Currently I am working on a system set up to allow the company and its various departments to see what stage orders are at. I am doing this by storing comma separated 'statuses' in an orders management table so we can track recursion (what employee did what on what day, etc)

SQL fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91cd6a

```
o.id  Order#  om.id       status
--  ----       --         ----
1   1      2          Delivered
3   2          4          Order Received
3   2          4,5        Order On Hold (parts needed)
4   2          4,5,6      Ready for Delivery
5   2          4,5,6,2    Delivered
6   3          2          Delivered
```

My desired result would be something like:

```
3 => [Order: 3, Status: 2]
2 => [Order: 2, Status: 2,4,5,6]
1 => [Order: 1, Status: 2]
```

However I am currently getting every result;

```
3 => [Order: 3, Status: 2]
2 => [Order: 2, Status: 2,4,5,6]
2 => [Order: 2, Status: 4,5,6]
2 => [Order: 2, Status: 5,6]
1 => [Order: 1, Status: 2]
```

This is the current query I am using:

```
"SELECT * FROM orders LEFT JOIN orders_mgmt ON orders_mgmt.om_order_id = orders.orders_ID WHERE orders_distributor_ID = '$dashID' AND orders_process_status != '2' ORDER BY orders_mgmt.om_timestamp DESC"
```

Comment: It's pretty hard what you want to achieve with that table structure, did you think about 2 related tables with a 1:N relationship? You would have the orders in one table and the statuses in other. With that, what you need would be pretty easy.

Comment: They're actually in separate tables now; let me clean up/export an SQL fiddle.

Comment: That would help a lot, XD

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91cd6a

Comment: Attached; I tried to minify it as much as I could

Comment: that's cool, but I still see 'om_status' as a string field of concatenated by comma values. Why do you have it in that way? Why don't you have a "history table" in which you add every action as a new row with its own timestamp?

Comment: Ah, I actually originally had it but thought THIS was the easier way. I can make that change easily on the PHP, could you provide an SQL solution to that type of query then? The issue is they are checkboxes, so I needed them all in a single array for when php looped over them, so it could set previously marked ones as true or false. This, to me, felt the most efficient to get them 'together' if that makes sense. I'm absolutely open to suggestions and had it as 2, 3, 5, etc. being separate SQL entries last night. I thought I was overthinking it then lol.

Comment: So, from your SQLFiddle, I guess, row 3 in orders_mgmt is wrong because it has number 2 repeated, and it shouldn't, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from all you told me, this it what I finished with:

```
SELECT 
  o.id
, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT om.status ORDER BY om.status ASC SEPARATOR ',' ) status
FROM orders o 
INNER JOIN orders_mgmt om
ON om.order_id = o.id
GROUP BY o.id
```

I've done some changes in your tables, to make them easier to work with, check the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a9f8/8

What I've done:

- I store status checkboxes as a row in the table (check rows 3, 4 and 5 in orders_mgmt table) If they mark 3 checks, you store 3 rows. That way, you only have to use DISTINCT with the GROUP BY clause and you'll have it. If you wanted to have a resume table (I mean, a specific table with only that values in other table, to reduce load as you reduce inner joins and the size of the query, NOTE that this will break the principles of relational DDBB, but in occasions is better) you could make a trigger that after insert will concat the values and insert in the orders table, in the status field
- From my experience, I'm guessing you are using that table field names because you don't know the aliases sintaxis (at least, I did the same until I discovered themm XD). Change the names to short names and then refer them with the alias (see that I wrote orders_mgmt as om and then used it with the group by and the select). Also, don't mix uppercase and lowercase, always lowercase with underscore, to keep a standard with yourself.
- To finish, NEVER use a the * wildcard in a select, they are the devil! It may slow you down your queries highly (I've seen reductions by ten times in the execution of the time of a query after changing '*' for the name of the fields.

Well, hope this will help you to achieve what you're looking for, XD. I know that I made more things related to code review, but I couldn't help it, XD